# li attribute returns undefined

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav list on the side of my bootstrap page and I would like to grab the value of the custom attribute of each item each time it is clicked. I have tried numerous various methods but I can't seem to figure out why the attribute keeps returning undefined.

Here is some sample HTML:

```
<ul id="list" class="nav nav-list">              
    <li class=""><a href="#" myval="firstValue">Item 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" myval="secondValue">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the jQuery:

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li:has(a[href^="#"])', function () {
    var currentVal= $(this).attr('myval');
    alert(currentVal);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom attribute isn't on the LI. You have to get the attribute from it's child.

```
var currentVal= $(this).children('a').attr('myval');
```

Comment: Ahh, you're right! It worked! Thank you very much :)
Would my code have worked if it was 
`<li class="active" myval="firstValue"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `myval`, but `data-myval`:

```
<a href="#" data-myval="firstValue">

$("#list").on('click', 'li:has(a[href^="#"])', function () {
    alert($(this).children('a[href^="#"]').data('myval'));
});
```

Also note that the target of the click is `li` and `:has` does not select anything.  You could just bind to the `a` by removing the `:has` too.